# Build gerrit events-log plugin

Tags: gerrit

I am trying to build gerrit events-log plugin via Buck build, but its failing with error:

```
root@monkey:/tmp/events-log# buck build plugin
[-] PROCESSING BUCK FILES...FINISHED 0.3s [100%]
[+] DOWNLOADING... (0.00 B/S, TOTAL: 0.00 B, 0 Artifacts)
[+] BUILDING...0.2s [19%] (3/19 JOBS, 0 UPDATED, 0.0% CACHE MISS)
|=> //lib/commons:dbcp__download_bin...  0.1s (running genrule[0.0s])
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".bootstrap/_pex/pex.py", line 320, in execute
File ".bootstrap/_pex/pex.py", line 253, in _wrap_coverage
File ".bootstrap/_pex/pex.py", line 285, in _wrap_profiling
File ".bootstrap/_pex/pex.py", line 363, in _execute
File ".bootstrap/_pex/pex.py", line 421, in execute_entry
File ".bootstrap/_pex/pex.py", line 426, in execute_module
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 180, in run_module
  fname, loader, pkg_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
  exec code in run_globals
File "bucklets/tools/download_file.py", line 198, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 535, in check_call
  retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
  return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
  errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
  raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Can somebody please tell how to fix it?
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

If you haven't already figured this out, ensure that 'zip' is installed and in your $PATH.

[github issue for similar failure in a different plugin](https://github.com/davido/gerrit-oauth-provider/issues/15)